# how to get only time from datetime like(2011-04-23 09:30:51:01) in java or javascript or jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

how to get only time from datetime like(2011-04-23 09:30:51:01) in java or javascript or jquery

Comment: Wondering. Where'd he had to use this? "in java or javascript or jquery"

Answer (score 19):

In Java:

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS");
SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = parseFormat.parse("2011-04-23 09:30:51:01");
System.out.println(printFormat.format(date)); // prints 09:30:51
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm (or any other JavaScript `Date` reference)? In particular see the `getHours()`, `getMinutes()` and `getSeconds()` functions.

Other references:

- [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)
- http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/
- http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript,

```
var d = new Date("2011-04-20 09:30:51:01");
d.getHours(); // => 9
d.getMinutes(); // =>  30
d.getSeconds(); // => 51
```

Full details on Javascript's Date object are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: not working...show message `NaN`